# Showing a Side menu on Click of annotation in mapview

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am trying to show a tableView sliding from right  on the click of an annotation in mapview,can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code snippet???

Comment: I am not getting where to start from i am adding the view on  didSelectAnnotationView for now .- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
        
        self.dataDotsHoverView.frame = CGRectMake(1024, 50, 320, 718);
        [view addSubview:self.dataDotsHoverView];
    } completion:nil];
}

Answer (score 0):

you can use following `delegate` method of `MKMapView` to get selected `annotation` in `mapview`.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    // add your custom tableview in view object and show it with animation
//    [view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

Comment: yes i am using this delegate method and adding the table view in the annotation view but the result is not positive.  self.dataDotsHoverView.frame = CGRectMake(1024, 50, 320, 718); [view addSubview:self.dataDotsHoverView];

Comment: you are adding in wrong `x position`. try using CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 718).

1024 as `x position` will add outside window bounds.